# How to debug OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument error for Anki (open source flashcard app) addon Morphman

Tags: python, spacy, anki

Trying to use/debug an add-on used for open source Python based flashcard app Anki. Uses a python link to communicate with Spacy, python based open source NLP processor. the add-on ,Morphman, communicates with Spacy and gets POS tagging and dependency labels. Get this exception when I attempt to pass certain fields of a flashcard through the language processor through a "recalc", which computes this for all user-specified flashcards.

Asking here because it seems the project has been vacated and devs aren't actively supporting it.

Add-on
https://github.com/rteabeault/MorphMan/tree/rteabeault/spacy_support

```
Debug info:
Anki 2.1.35 (84dcaa86) Python 3.8.0 Qt 5.14.2 PyQt 5.14.2
Platform: Windows 10
Flags: frz=True ao=True sv=1
Add-ons, last update check: 2021-03-28 23:12:08

Caught exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Anki2\addons21\Morphman__init__.py", line 17, in onMorphManRecalc
    main.main()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Anki2\addons21\Morphman\morph\main.py", line 573, in main
    allDb = mkAllDb(cur)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Anki2\addons21\Morphman\morph\main.py", line 195, in mkAllDb
    ms = getMorphemes(morphemizer, fieldValue, ts)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Anki2\addons21\Morphman\morph\morphemes.py", line 166, in getMorphemes
    ms = morphemizer.getMorphemesFromExpr(expression)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Anki2\addons21\Morphman\morph\morphemizer.py", line 51, in getMorphemesFromExpr
    morphs = self._getMorphemesFromExpr(expression)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Anki2\addons21\Morphman\morph\deps\spacy\morphemizer.py", line 40, in _getMorphemesFromExpr
    self.proc.stdin.flush()
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Comment: Based on the Errno 22 and that you're flushing stdin this is probably due to a Windows process not having stdin, which happens sometimes. Are you sure your code is tested to run on Windows? It might only work on Linux/Mac.

Comment: Was on windows- then I installed everything on Ubuntu and it worked.

Comment: The problem above results from an encoding problem to terminal (on the Japanese model, specifically) in Windows. My instinct tells me this behavior has resulted from a new Windows feature update- the terminal effectively is displaying Japanese characters as the Unicode 'unknown character' glyph, so when they get passed through to SudachiPy, it fails, and an exception results.

Comment: Oddly enough though, on Ubuntu, when upgrading from sudachipy 0.4.5 (which worked) to 0.4.9, I got the same exception that I did on Windows. Upgrading once again on Ubuntu to 0.5.2 resolved the issue. Is this coincidental? Windows is still broken all around. @polm23

Comment: It is also worth noting that other language models for Spacy (english, spanish) worked with no issues whatsoever.

Comment: The place your stack trace shows is in Morphman, not spaCy, so I'm surprised it depends on the language. How the terminal displays characters shouldn't affect what Sudachi does internally. Can you print Japanese, without spaCy? No idea why you would get the issue on Ubuntu.

Comment: I think what happened was when, on the link, where Anki passes the strings to be parsed as an input to the terminal, when it happens to be Japanese, happens to display the incorrect way, throwing off an error in SudachiPy saying it can't parse unknown characters, and then is sent back through the morphemizer.. since it isn't formatted the way it is expecting, and is an error message instead, is throws an invalid argument. This is all ( I think?) because Morphman reads the terminal output where an instance of Spacy is running. There is a python link to communicate between Morphman and Spacy.

Comment: On windows, I can not even type characters to input into the terminal. They show up as the same error glyphs as before.

Comment: Oh, Morphman isn't calling spaCy as a library, it's calling a subprocess? That's weird and could definitely cause issues. If you can't type Japanese in your terminal at all you'll have to resolve that before you can do anything.

Comment: Will try to get that working, but in the meantime, I'm curious why the same exception was thrown on Ubuntu with the various SudachiPy versions. Will continue to investigate